# Working with primitives in XNA

Tags: bitmap, xna, drawing, primitive, texture2d

Perhaps I am trying to use XNA in a way that it was not designed, but I would very much like to be able to draw my own primitives and save them as a bitmap, or a texture2D, or anything that will hold a few 2d lines for me. My goal is to program a game where the textures are created procedurally, instead of just being loaded from the content manager.

If it helps to know, I've made a Shape class that stores polygons, and I probably could just tell spriteBatch to draw each line out, but I'm trying to optimize by storing commonly used shapes somewhere, instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [RenderTarget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.rendertarget%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx) for your task. Something like this:

```
// var to store your drawing
Texture2D newShape;

// drawing will be on this target
RenderTarget2D rt = new RenderTarget2D(GraphicsDevice, width, height);
SpriteBatch sb = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

// set to render all to render target
GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(rt); 

GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Transparent); 

sb.Begin();

// Draw what you want here.

sb.End()

// Return to drawing on "main" buffer
GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);

// Save the texture you just drawn
newShape = rt;
```

Comment: Awesome! I would only need to do this whenever a new shape that has never been added before is added. While I researched this, I came across the idea that starting and stopping sprite-batch often to do this sort of thing was a bad idea. I will test this and share results.

Comment: Please do, I'd be interested in seeing what you come up with

Comment: Hmm. I have not been able to get this to work. It seems that changing render targets while sprite batch is running produces some very crazy results.

Comment: @MaxKessler I can't say I used this technique much, but I've used it successfully. However I didn't changed RenderTarget in SpriteBatch run, you should try to separate "dynamic" texture creation and final render in separate batch runs.